# Displaying HTML table at specific time of day using PHP

Tags: php, datetime-format

Is it possible to display html table only at say `10:00 AM` to `16:00 PM` using PHP? If possible what is the most elegant way of doing it or at least a better way.Anyone who can help me with information on how to tackle the problem.

Comment: Try to use [settimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) in javascript  run ajax call to your php code based on time

Comment: If the provided solution was helpful, please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, try(`16:00 PM` is invalid time btw):

```
<?php

if(date('H:i') > "10:00" && date('H:i') < "16:00")
{
    //HTML TABLE HERE
}
```

This will simple get the current time and compare it accordingly.

Comment: it really worked as I needed, I have learnt a lot from  both the answer and the comments.My server time and the time on my PC have  a 2 hour gape at first I thought the answer was failing me, I put this just in case someone will face the same problem.